# Probability of a certain number of good parts out of a lot

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I did not find quite this question searching here and on Google, which probably means I do not know the correct terminology.

Looking for a general formulation of the probability of a certain number of parts out of a lot being good given a certain failure rate.  For instance, if I have $n$ parts, and each has a $Y$ probability of being defective.  What are the odds that $k$ of them won't be defective, (with $k \le n$ of course!) .  I thought about it some and looked at some general combinatorics explanations, but that learning is too far in my past for me to puzzle it out quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It sounds like that you may be in need of the Binomial Probability Distribution

Comment: Lets say each part has a probability of failure of $p$, then, following Atif Farooq's suggestion, this is as simply as the expected value of a binomial distribution of k elements. Then, the number you are looking for is just $kp$.